# Select where result with additional row above or below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

This is the sample table

```
SELECT NoPolisi, ComLocID, Jenis, TglValid, rn 
FROM  (
          SELECT NoPolisi, ComLocID, Jenis, TglValid, NoPolisiBaru,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NoPolisi ORDER BY TglValid) rn 
          FROM MstData.dbo.Ms_UbahBentukArmada
      ) A
WHERE NoPolisi = 'BK 8819 CF'
```

And here is the select result query with where tglValid between 2 dates

```
DECLARE 
    @DateFrom smalldatetime = '20170101',
    @DateTo smalldatetime = '20171201'
SELECT NoPolisi, ComLocID, Jenis, TglValid, rn 
FROM  (
          SELECT NoPolisi, ComLocID, Jenis, TglValid, NoPolisiBaru, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NoPolisi ORDER BY TglValid) rn 
          FROM MstData.dbo.Ms_UbahBentukArmada
      ) A
WHERE NoPolisi = 'BK 8819 CF' 
AND   TglValid BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
```

The result of query above is

[image]

My Question is, Can i get The selected Result have an additional row above or below so the result have include row rn=5 or include row rn=2 ?

edit:
in the @gotqn answer it used

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [id] INT
    ,[date] DATETIME2(0)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([id], [date])
VALUES (100, '2000-01-01')
      ,(110, '2016-03-01')
      ,(120, '2017-06-06')
      ,(130, '2017-07-01')
      ,(140, '2018-01-01');

DECLARE 
    @DateFrom smalldatetime = '20170401',
    @DateTo smalldatetime = '20170430';

    WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS [rn]
          ,IIF
          (
            [date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            OR
            LAG([date]) OVER(ORDER BY [date]) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            ,1
            ,0
           ) AS [in_interval]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
-- WHERE [in_interval] = 1;
```

but if the date range is in the middle like the code above
it must return the row 2 :

```
id      date                rn      in_interval
100     2000-01-01 00:00:00 1       0
110     2016-03-01 00:00:00 2       1
120     2017-06-06 00:00:00 3       0
130     2017-07-01 00:00:00 4       0
140     2018-01-01 00:00:00 5       0
```

Thanks For Helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to be able to get:

- the biggest `rn` smaller then your minimum output data `rn`
- the smallest `rn` bigger then your maximum output data `rn`

As the `rn` is calculating in the `SELECT` [phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) in order to use it we need to materialized the results. Then, using `UNION ALL` add the desired records using `WHERE [rn] = (SELECT MIN(rn) - 1 FROM data)` or `WHERE [rn] = (SELECT max(rn) + 1 FROM data)`.

Below, I am using another approach using `self join`. So, this query:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [id] INT
    ,[date] DATETIME2(0)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([id], [date])
VALUES (100, '2000-01-01')
      ,(110, '2016-03-01')
      ,(120, '2017-06-06')
      ,(130, '2017-07-01')
      ,(140, '2018-01-01');

DECLARE 
    @DateFrom smalldatetime = '20170101',
    @DateTo smalldatetime = '20171201';

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS [rn]
          ,CASE WHEN [date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [in_interval]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource DS1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[rn] = DS2.[rn] - 1;
```

[image]

So, you need to add `WHERE DS1.[in_interval] = 1 OR DS2.[in_interval] = 1`. In order to get the next row, change the `ON` clause from this:

```
ON DS1.[rn] = DS2.[rn] - 1
```

to this:

```
ON DS1.[rn] = DS2.[rn] + 1
```

or add other self join to get the two rows.

---

For, `SQL Server 2012+`, you can use `LEAD` and `LAG` function to calculated if row should be included:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS [rn]
          ,IIF
          (
            [date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            OR
            LAG([date]) OVER(ORDER BY [date]) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            ,1
            ,0
           ) AS [in_interval]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
-- WHERE [in_interval] = 1;
```

---

We need to add additional column to count how many rows are in the range. If none of rows is in the range, we are extracting the one row using `UNION ALL`:

```
  WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS [rn]
          ,IIF
          (
            [date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            OR
            LAG([date]) OVER(ORDER BY [date]) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
            ,1
            ,0
           ) AS [in_interval]
         ,SUM(IIF( [date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo, 1, 0)) OVER() valid_dates 
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE [in_interval] = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [date] < @DateFrom
        AND [valid_dates] = 0
    ORDER BY [rn] DESC
) DS
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answer.
the result i want are like this

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [id] INT
    ,[date] DATETIME2(0)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([id], [date])
VALUES (100, '2000-01-01')
      ,(100, '2016-03-01')
      ,(100, '2017-06-06')
      ,(100, '2017-07-01')
      ,(100, '2018-01-01');

DECLARE 
    @DateFrom smalldatetime = '20170401',
    @DateTo smalldatetime = '20180101';


SELECT * FROM @DataSource WHEre date between @DateFrom AND @DateTo
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, max(date) date FROM @DataSource where date < @DateFrom group by id
```

Thanks @gotqn for the time to help